# open GL ES object not rendering correctly

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have a 3d object that I made in SketchUp. Using a tool I found on the web, I have converted this to a .h file listing all the vertices and norms. The problem is when I render the object is has gaps which you can see through. And I havent been able to locate the problem. Is there a obvious reason for this?

[converter Pearl file](http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/)

Ive added a link to the site where I got the Pearl file that takes the .obj and converts it to a .h

[image: Screen Shot]

Thease are supposed to be 3d J's as you can see there are gaps through them.

Comment: There are probably lots of things that could be going on.  First question: do you have backface culling turned on?  If so, turn it off and see if you see a difference.

Comment: This question is too vague. What is this tool you found "on the web" and what is it doing? How are you drawing the objects? I bet it's got the drawing order of some triangles backwards.

Comment: I will double check the the triangle order. cheers

Comment: Can you post image of problem? Could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use tools that turn 3D models into .h files, it's a horrible way to import data into your code. Especially if you need to edit the objects or load many of them. Instead write or find a model loader that reads the files itself, you can then actually do tests on the data to see if it is valid. The wavefront obj format is quite easy to parse.

You can usually see through objects if the winding order is backwards. It can also happen if you're trying to draw a complex object that is made from separate pieces like the teapot that contains a lid that isn't attached to the body.